# error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0 - Brackets

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, shared-library

I installed Brackets on Lubuntu 13.04.

When I use the command `brackets` to open it, I get the error:
`/usr/lib/brackets/Brackets: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

How can I get Brackets to work?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I found the solution 
[in this Github issue](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/4720).

You have to link the existing `libudev.so.1` to the requested `libudev.so.0`; to do so, run the command

`ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0`

NOTE: You might need to prefix this command with `sudo` to gain root privileges. In which case it would look like this:

`sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0`

Answer (score 3):

What you can try is to link the installed files to the ones the program is looking for:

```
sudo apt-get install libudev1 && cd /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ && sudo ln -s libudev.so.1 libudev.so.0
```

Comment: Well that worked for my spotify problem

Answer (score 0):

Also, as **peterflynn** [said](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/5494#issuecomment-50828455)

> Note for anyone else encountering this (from #8553): a "libudev.so.0" error when installing Brackets on 64-bit Linux may indicate you downloaded a 32-bit version of Brackets by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the solution

```
sudo ln -s <libudevpath>/libudev.so.1 <libudevpath>/libudev.so.0
```

However, if you just blindly assume to find `libudev1` in `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`, it might not be there. If `libudev1` installs somewhere else, you can find it using:

```
sudo find / -name "libudev.so*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the solution

```
sudo ln -s <libudevpath>/libudev.so.1 <libudevpath>/libudev.so.0
```

This creates a symbolic link between two files. Whenever an application looks for `<libudevpath>/libudev.so.0` (which deosn't really exist), it will follow this link and use `<libudevpath>/libudev.so.1` instead.

However, if you just blindly assume to find `libudev1` in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, it might not be there. If `libudev1` installs somewhere else, you can find it using:

```
sudo find / -name "libudev.so*"
```