# Applications installed with sudo dpkg -i are not launching

Tags: software-installation

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I installed `pencil` and `koala` using `sudo dpkg -i` command, and they appear on the launcher but when I click on them nothing happens.

How can I fix this?

```
$ which pencil
/usr/bin/pencil
$ which koala
/usr/bin/koala
$ sudo ./koala
/usr/share/koala/koala: error while loading shared libraries: 
libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ sudo ./pencil
/usr/bin/pencil: 4: /usr/bin/pencil: /usr/bin/xulrunner: not found
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ax25-node kde-l10n-engb libax25 linux-headers-3.13.0-32
  linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic openbsd-inetd
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

Comment: May be library issues..run those from command line and check for any error messages..

Comment: i tried chmod +x, still nothing

Comment: Open a terminal and type `which pencil` and `which koala` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @heemayl I edited my question

Comment: Ok..now run `pencil` and then `koala` from the terminal and check what happens then.

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install -f` say?

Comment: @heemayl I've added the output from trying to execute pencil and koala, @muru I've added the output for `apt-get install -f`

Comment: I think you installed a package for an older version of Ubuntu, since it is `libudev.so.1` now. See http://askubuntu.com/q/125980/158442, http://askubuntu.com/q/330935/158442

Comment: @muru libudev.so.1 is already symlinked to libudev.so.0

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; I opened `/usr/bin/pencil` with nano, and changed `/usr/bin/xulrunner --app "/usr/share/pencil/application.ini"` to `/usr/bin/firefox --app "/usr/share/pencil/application.ini"`

Then I installed xulrunner for koala.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/usr/share/applications/your-app-that-doesnt-launch` and **right click** on `yourApp`and go to `Properties -> Permissions` and **check** `allow executing file as program` if it is not checked. Done!!

Comment: Tried that it did not work