# Sudo is not working (libsudo_util error)

Tags: 16.04, sudo

I was trying to delete a folder and messed up. I'm getting this error while I'm trying to use `sudo`:

```
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libsudo_util.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you know what you did when you "messed up"? Did you delete the wrong folder, maybe?

Comment: i created a folder in usr/lib and wanted to delete that. i did with rm -rf  foldername

Comment: the folder name was sudo and i deleted it

Comment: Yeah, that's not good. I honestly don't know how to replace it (without using the `sudo` command in the process) -- maybe someone else has some ideas.

Comment: i tried to install sudo from recovery mode, it says you already have the latest version of sudo.

Comment: Have you tried *re*installing it?

Answer (score 0):

When `sudo` not working:

```
pkexec chmod go-w /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

If problem is not solved you can [check](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/4720)

The another [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330935/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libudev-so-0-brackets). You can check both the linked , may help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could open ubuntu software (gui) 
 Search for "synaptic"

Install synaptic package manager .

open synaptic package manager and search for sudo
Right click the mouse on sudo choose **mark for Reinstallation**
Then click the big apply button
I think sudo will work agin for you Kevin

Comment: Since Synaptic must run as root to function, this is unlikely to work.

Comment: yes Synaptic must have root permission . As long as he could log into ubuntu , he can use root permission in gui programs . Sudo isn't the root. sudo is just a package gives the main user in ubuntu root permission